# Preventing Attacks Scanning for PHPMyAdmin etc

Tags: linux, web-scanners

I have a Linux web server running Rails and each time I check the Nginx logs I find attempts to access PHPMyAdmin, database and admin directories such as this:

```
190.196.161.110 - - [16/Oct/2011:23:37:31 +0100] "GET //PHPMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Made by ZmEu @ WhiteHat Team - www.whitehat.ro"
```

The attacks are coming from a variety of different IP addresses and they just increment version numbers and check each directory, e.g. GET //PHPMyAdmin 1.0/, GET //PHPMyAdmin 1.1/ etc.

Will this affect the performance of my web server much?  Also, is there a way to automatically ban IP addresses that do such things e.g. like fail2ban for ssh log-in attempts.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Apache for such applications, you may want to look into [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/), [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) and/or [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/). The latter two are more geared towards brute force and DoS attacks. ModSecurity though has a ton of stuff under its banner.

Answer (score 3):

Fail2ban has an [example script](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_apache_myadmin_filter) for doing this from Apache log files. Basically look for the PHPMyAdmin string in your logs with a 404.